# ZipArchive - Zip file from a List<byte[]> - Creates Large Empty Zip File

Tags: c#

I have an List<byte[]>.   I'm trying to create an Zip file using ZipArchive (System.IO.Compression).

I have the following code. It creates the Zip file, on average 20 MB. But the zip file is empty.
What is wrong with the following code. I can see values for all the vars.

```
                   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create,false))
                        {
                            int x = 0;

                            foreach (var file in byteArrayList)
                            {
                                var entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetRandomFileName(), CompressionLevel.Fastest);

                                using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(file))
                                using (var zipEntryStream = entry.Open())
                                {
                                    //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                                }
                                x++;
                            }                           
                        }
                        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "TEST.zip");                     
                    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is empty" exactly? Have you opened it in a hex editor and it is all `00`s? Does it fail to open? Does it open but the file list is empty? The files are listed but none of them work? Please be precise.

Comment: For what it's worth, why not just do `zipEntryStream.Write(file)` instead of using a separate memory stream for it? Also, no need to pass `false` to the ZipArchive constructor's `leaveOpen` parameter, since you're going to dispose the memory stream afterwards anyway.

Comment: Possible you just need to do `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` right before the return.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment The documentation for `ToArray()` actually states "Writes the stream contents to a byte array, regardless of the Position property.", so a `Seek` should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Set the third argument of the `ZipArchive` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Compression_ZipArchive__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_IO_Compression_ZipArchiveMode_System_Boolean_) to `true`.

Otherwise the underlying stream (here it's `ms`) is closed when `archive` is disposed. That's why `ms` is empty afterwards.

Comment: I did set 3rd arg to true... stlll empty.. any ideas?

Comment: `ToArray()` is explicitly designed to work properly even when the stream is disposed, as explained in the documentation. The only thing setting `leaveOpen` to true here does is making things a bit cleaner by not trying to dispose the stream twice (the second disposal being a no-op anyway).

Comment: @jon, are you sure that `byteArrayList` is not empty ?

Comment: bytleArrayList has 4 - {byte[22369762]}.  But NOW getting ZIP is invalid. Any ideas? thx

Comment: The issue is with the CreateEntry 'name'.  If  I use what I provided above it works - simple name. But in my actual case the CreateEntry is   several strings concatenated... like  Path.GetRandomFileName()+"-"+DateTimeStamp.  Not sure if it's the 'dash' , or what. No errors.  If I change it the name to '1.pdf' it works fine.